# OALSimpleAudio not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

Xcode is giving me error of "No known class method for selector 'sharedInstance'" for this code:

```
// access audio object
OALSimpleAudio *audio = [OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance];
// play sound effect
[audio playEffect:@"Hello.mp3"];
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: did you #import the OALSimpleAudio.h?

Comment: I added #import "OALSimpleAudio.h" but still have the same error. Any idea?

Comment: you are using cocos2d v3 right? Are the ObjectAL classes in your project?

Comment: How do i check if it's v3? The libs folder of my cocos2d-iphone folder has a modified date of Jan 30 2014. There are ObjectAL classes in the external folder of that folder.

Answer (score 1):

In a very early release of Cocos2D v3 the header search paths were incorrect. 
Can you check that "Build Settings" -> "Header Search Paths" contains this search path:

"Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/external/ObjectAL"

[image]

Comment: Yes, the search path is correct. What else might be causing the error?

Comment: I want to add that this is an ARC Semantic Issue. How do i fix it?

Comment: If i disable ARC, it gives me the warning of "Class method '+sharedInstance' not found (return type defaults to 'id')." What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If this is still unresolved, in my case I had my own (different) version of a SynthesizeSingleton.h file in the project which was not compatible with the OALSimpleAudio code. Removing this additional SynthesizeSingleton.h file fixed this issue.